# Browser Fingerprinting in TAILS

Tags: tails, browsers

How concerned should I be about fingerprinting of my browser in TAILS?

I am not sure what I can do.

How can I minimize the risks of browser fingerprinting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tails uses the standard Tor Browse and so any Tails users should look just like any other Tor user.

> How can I minimize the risks of browser fingerprinting?

This is pretty simple:

Don't alter the browser by adding extra plugins or addons.
Don't change any of the about:config settings.
Either keep the browser window maximized or at the standard resolution.

The majority of websites will see you as "just another Tor user" and can't pick you out from anyone else.